# fake news detection using pickle

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I'm trying to build fake news detection and deployed with Flask app. Everything is OK with manual entry, but when I tried to pickle the model to use it later with Flask, I found some error with my code. I'm using Python 3.8 with Anaconda (Jupyter notebook) and in the future PyCharm to configure the Flask app.
I built the model and trained it.

```py
def output_lable(n):
    if n == 0:
        return "Fake News"
    elif n == 1:
        return "Real News"
    
def manual_testing(news):
    testing_news = {"text":[news]}
    new_def_test = pd.DataFrame(testing_news)
    new_def_test["text"] = new_def_test["text"].apply(wordopt) 
    new_x_test = new_def_test["text"]
    new_xv_test = vectorization.transform(new_x_test)
    pred_LR = LR.predict(new_xv_test)
    pred_DT = DT.predict(new_xv_test)
    pred_GBC = GBC.predict(new_xv_test)
    pred_RFC = RFC.predict(new_xv_test)

    return print("\n\nLR Prediction: {} \nDT Prediction: {} \nGBC Prediction: {} \nRFC Prediction: {}".format(output_lable(pred_LR[0]),
                                                                                                              output_lable(pred_DT[0]), 
                                                                                                              output_lable(pred_GBC[0]), 
                                                                                                              output_lable(pred_RFC[0])))
```

For manual entry, I used this

```
news = str(input())
manual_testing(news)
```

and it is perfect, but I dump the model with

```
pickle.dump(manual_testing,open("model.pkl","wb"))
```

then reload it again with the code

```
model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl","rb"))
print(model.predict(["this is a fake news"])
```

I get the following  after run it

````
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```<ipython-input-66-f1b38a468d27> in <module>
      1 model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl","rb"))
      2 news ="this is a fake"
----> 3 print(model.predict([news]))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'predict'
````

Can someone please help me to understand why is this happening and how to prevent it from happening again?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
print(model.predict(["this is a fake news"])
```

use:

```
print(model.predict(["this is a fake news"]))
```

There is a missing closing bracket. And the error has nothing to do with `pickle`.

Comment: thanks alot but when I edit it it gives me this       AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-2df99b8bb0f7> in <module>
      1 model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl","rb"))
----> 2 print(model.predict(["this is a fake news"]))

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'predict

Comment: From what you provided in the question, it seems rather obvious - `manual_testing` is a function, isn't it? So you cannot treat it as an instance of an object and call methods of such a "to-be object".

Comment: so how can I do it

Comment: Post your whole code - what are you serializing to a pickle and we can work off that. Best as a separate question, after accepting this answer.